# Facebook Graph API - building the request for instagram insights follower_demographics field with breakdown

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook graph api v19, recently the audience_gender_age.. audience_country..  have been deprecated in v18 so I'm trying to use follower_demographics.. see here for docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/insights/#breakdown

but the breakdown feature seems to not work unless I'm building it incorrectly. If i do it individually ie.

```
breakdown=country or breakdown=city
```

it works but once i try to add multiple like this:

```
breakdown=country,city,gender
```

it doesnt work, it also doesnt work if i add another metric like:

```
metric=follower_demographics,online_followers
```

I'm trying to get this working but i keep seeing errors --  **"message": "An unknown error has occurred."**, or if I add online_followers: error -- **(#100) The following metric (online_followers) is incompatible with the metric type (total_value)**

```
insights?metric=follower_demographics,online_followers&period= lifetime&metric_type=total_value&breakdown=country,city,age,gender
```